# WordPress homepage choice

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

Would it be possible to have index.php of domain.com to be a dropdown to choose the homepage based on whether the user is in city x or city y? I'd then like a cookie to be set that remembered the user's choice.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Could you add a little more detail on what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your template header.php you can add a piece of code to get the data from the visitor country/city and then use header location php to redirect to where u want them to go.

or u can build a landing page and display what u want.

refer to [landingPage](http://xtremenews.info/2011/07/20/landing-pagesplash-page-en-wordpress-o-joomla/)